# why the 555 timer output is not the same as my calculation

Tags: oscillator, boost, 555

Hi may i ask why is my calculation for the 555 timer of U2 is not the same as the simulator. U1 output signal 22064.24Hz, 92.81% duty cycle.

t=1.1* R_1*C_1

t=1.1* 10k* 2.2n

t=1.1* 10k*2.2n

t=0.0242ms

From my calculation i got 0.0242ms for the monostable output but the simulation result is kind of off for U2(out) output which doesnt seem to match up with my calculation and why is the result is not uniform?

[image: image 2]
schematic diagram ^
[image: simulation result]
U2 output signal ^
[image: trigger for U2 and output from U1]
trigger for U2 and output from U1^

Comment: Well what the actual value is then? Also the actual chips are not accurate to 0.01%, maybe to 2%, and real world resistors and capacitors have tolerances too.

Comment: well from my simulation i got 0.0242ms. And the 1st T_on is 54.24196µs and the 2nd onward is  4.1271057µs its like super far away and i not sure why the result is not uniform.

Comment: Did you read justme's comment?  Ideal simulation vs tolerances of real components.

Comment: The fact that you use numbers like: 54.24196µs and 4.1271057µs tells me you need to learn about **component tolerances**. As mentioned in the comments, components have tolerances, like 5% or 10% for resistors and 20% for capacitors. So a 1nF capacitor can be 0.8 nF up to 1.2 nF. Then talking about 54.24196µs is **silly**, an experienced EE would write: 54µs (and even that can vary between 43µs and 65µs). Realize that to really get 54.24196µs you need components with 0.00001% accuracy! I challenge you to find these. And your circuit doesn't need that level of accuracy anyway.

Comment: Also, using capacitors as small as 1 nF with the 555 timer is **close to the 555's limits**. I suggest making the timing capacitors **10 x larger** so 10 nF and 22 nF and the timing resistors **10 x smaller** to keep the same timing.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie or, really, just dump the darn 555s and design something that does what you need instead without them...

Comment: @MarcusMüller I agree, this looks like a **boost converter**, hmm there are ICs designed specifically to make a boost converter. Why not use one of those? Unless this project is for "educational purposes" of course.

Comment: Oh and OP, regarding your "It is not the same", realize that in electronics , things are almost **never** the same. Question is, is it **close enough?** Read this: https://unijokes.com/joke-11140/

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yeah, now that I look I noticed the inductor. Ummmm, Why on earth would someone care about the fine frequency of a boost converter built like this?

Comment: @Bimplrekkie @@MarcusMüller  sorry for the late reply i forget to mention at the monostable there is a 5V apply into the CV for about 3.95ms but when i remove the comparator it seem like the formula work but when i added the comparator the result change is there like any way for me to calculate the duty cycle and the period of the monostable 555timer output and yes its for educational purposes